# Flatpickr onchange event set dateStr to +1 day

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

```
var arrival = $('#datepicker');
    var departure = $('#datepicker1');

    arrival.flatpickr({
      dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
      disableMobile: true,
      locale: "de",
      minDate: "today",
      onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      departure.flatpickr({
        dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
        enableTime: false,
        minDate: dateStr,
      });
      departure.removeAttr('readonly');
      arrival.removeAttr('readonly');
    }
    });

    departure.flatpickr({
      dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
      disableMobile: true,
      locale: "de",
      minDate: "today",
      onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      arrival.flatpickr({
        dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
        enableTime: false,
        minDate: dateStr,
      });
      departure.removeAttr('readonly');
      arrival.removeAttr('readonly');
    }
    });
```

Hi everybody
I should create a booking form with Flatpickr and should get departure date +1 as arrival date but this is first time for me to as Flatpickr , if can someone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using `new Date(selectedDates).fp_incr(1)` in combination with the Flatpickr config function `onChange`.

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let arrival = $('#datepicker');
  let departure = $('#datepicker1');

  arrival.flatpickr({
    dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
    disableMobile: true,
    //locale: "de",
    minDate: "today",
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      //departure.set('maxDate', new Date(dateStr).fp_incr(5));
      departure.flatpickr({
        dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
        enableTime: false,
        minDate: new Date(selectedDates).fp_incr(1), // add 1 day
        //new Date(dateStr).fp_incr(1)
      });
      departure.removeAttr('readonly');
      arrival.removeAttr('readonly');
    }
  });

  departure.flatpickr({});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" style="width:200px;">
<input id="datepicker1" style="width:200px;">
```